# Convert .objs to .mat in python or a with a program in linux

Tags: python, linux, mesh, converters

Can anyone suggest a way, in python or a general tool in linux maybe to convert an obj into a .mat file?

I have some code like:

```
import eigen_solver as es
import scipy.io as sio

# load mesh
model = 'sphere4.mat'
mat = sio.loadmat(model)
V, F = mat['V'], mat['F']
```

But the meshes I want to use are in `.obj` format.
I'm not 100% sure how easy would be to write this from scratch, but I guess should be somehow straightforward, but if there's a tool I'd like to use it.

By `obj` I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file
By `mat` I mean the matlab `.mat` format.

Comment: the `.obj` extension does not inform on the format of the file. Can you give more information on this format ?

Comment: @Frodon please, read the update

Comment: Did you try to use the python API PyWaveFront (https://github.com/pywavefront/PyWavefront) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) to read in the obj file directly.

```
pip install meshio
```

```py
import meshio

mesh = meshio.read("foo.obj")
# mesh.points, mesh.cells, etc.
```

Comment: So they would be automatically converted into the `.mat` format? (A list for faces and a list for vertices specifically).

Comment: `mat` isn't strictly a format, just a container. It can hold any kind of data. And yes, you'll get a list of vertices and faces.

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know then.